# Angular 5 firebase dynamic pages - how to retrieve list from the list?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I've got this in my db  :

```
Profile {
UID {
  -name
  -username
     +projects {
     KEY {
     -url
     -name
        +info {
        -title
        -description        
          }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For example I create this project in the home page. I will show only project url and name. On project click it will go to the inner project window and show the title and description of that project.

**My question : How to make a pages which retrieves db info from this.project ?**

For example :

> HOME PAGE : url, name. - onclick --> project page - this.project.title, this project.description.

Comment: Do you use Angular Router? You can use a token for a route parameter. See https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter for more info.

Comment: Angular router won't give me project->info, only will make url.